# break association of 'enter' key with form submission

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to detect 'enter' key with respect to form without letting the form being submitted. How do I break this association?

```
document.forms[0].onkeypress = function (event) {
    e = window.event ? window.event : event;
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        //actions to be taken
    }
```

}

Though actions inside are taken properly, the page reloads upon completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to `return false` at the end of your function. Assuming that you're handling the form submission already in a `submit` event callback.

Answer (score 1):

Return `false` from your function:

```
document.forms[0].onkeypress = function (event) {
    e = window.event ? window.event : event;
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        //actions to be taken 

        return false;
    }    
}
```